# Pycharm con WSL2

Tags: python, pycharm, wsl

Estoy intentando configurar un interprete de Python remoto en Pycharm, el de WSL2, concretamente. He visto en todas partes que en la configuración del interprete me tendría que dejar seleccionar el interprete de WSL, pero no lo detecta o no aparece (imagen adjunta) y no sé como puedo hacerlo. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de porque puede pasar?

¡Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que es una característica propia de PyCharm Pro. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Comment: Hola Mateo, sí, tienes toda la razón... Tocará pagar. Gracias.